# automatic listings count down

Tags: javascript, php

hi all im attempting to add a time countdown on a page and or form for a members meet script where a member can be added to a submitted listings page for say 3 hours to show there availability how would i make this work where the user will automatically be removed from list after that time here is the form that ive done ready

```
<form action="" method="post">
Hours to be on list:  
<select name="hours">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select><br>
<input value="Add Me to Meet Today" type="submit">
</form>
```

any help would be much appreciated

ty jan x

Comment: `mysqli` wouldn't be related here. You probably want to use a cookie and JS.

Comment: On the query that you are running to list all members, place a condition that limits members that submitted `x` hours ago.

Comment: @WesleySchleumerdeGóes The X may differ from row to row depending on the value of the "hours" field. I'd suggest storing the expire date (now + hours) in the database and pulling records where expire date < now.

Comment: @chris85 Cookie is an option only if the only person required to see the list is the user who submitted it. Also: if using cookie, the code would have to manage every submitted record as a separate cookie. While possible, it doesn't look like an easy solution.